# mixins with LESS and visual studio

Tags: less

I'm using LESS with visual studio and it's working well,but now I'm trying using to use mixins for the first time.

I enter this code:

```
.box-sizing (@type: border-box) {
    -webkit-box-sizing: @type;
    -moz-box-sizing:    @type;
    box-sizing:         @type;
 }
```

but I'm getting Error from the visual studio compiler:

LESS: Unrecognised input

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: that code is ok - maybe some other code is causing the error?

Comment: Are you using Web Essentials to compile your less files?